# How to run LabView after installation?

Tags: software-installation

I have installed LabView on a Ubuntu virtual machine, but I cannot find any command or icon to run LabView. How to run it?

Comment: Please read and EDIT your question https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/lv-2022-q3-linux.html is pretty clear: "Insert and mount the LabVIEW installation media. As the root user in the mounted directory, enter sh ./INSTALL to install LabVIEW in the /usr/local directory. "  it will be `./LabView` "con to run LabView." you probably need to make one yourself.

Comment: @Rinzwind The installation is completed successfully but I can not locate the LabView in the `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The run command is `labview64`.